# multidimensional associative javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

i am in the need of creating a multidimensional associative object, and it is partially working.

simplified version:

```
var sources = {
    tales:  ['some content', 'some more content'],
    thehut: ['some content', 'some more content']
};
```

All i want is for the 'some content' and 'some more content' to have an alias, but i cannot get it working properly.

Comment: Define "alias". Do you still want them to be available in the array they're currently in?

Comment: If by "alias", you mean "string key", then you must make the internal items objects as arrays can only have numeric autoincrementing keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
var sources = {
    tales:  {name1:'some content', name2:'some more content'},
    thehut: {name1:'some content', name2:'some more content'}
};
```

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann: mafafu's code is correct, you must have a typo.

Comment: it works, i will mark as solution when i can :) thank you very much

Comment: i have another question actually. Is it possible to run through the array and read the aliases? not the actual values, but the aliases

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann: Yes, via a [`for-in` loop](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4). E.g., `var key; for (key in sources.tales) { /* ... */ }`. The proper term for what you're calling an "alias" is a "property name." These are objects, which have properties. `for-in` lets you enumerate the names of the properties in the object (provided the properties are enumerable; they can be or not, depending). All the ones you define the way mafafu showed will be enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are referring to with "alias", is this what you want?

```
var sources =  {
    tales : {some_content: 'content 1', some_more_content: 'content 2'},
    thehut: {some_content: 'content 3', some_more_content: 'content 4'}
};
```

You use this like this:

```
> sources.tales.some_content
  "content 1"
```

Comment: this is exactly what i want, i will just try it